# What's wrong with my function? I have function that finds all common chars and concatenates them into one string

Tags: c, string, function

I have function that finds all common chars and concatenates into one string.

```
char* commonString(char* p1,char* p2)
{
    char* res = "";
    for (int k=0;k<strlen(p1);k++)
    {
        for (int h=0;h<strlen(p2);h++)
        {
            if (p1[k] == p2[h])
            {
                strcat(res,&p1[k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;   
}
```

What's wrong with it? Can you review and help to fix it?

Example of I/O:
Example 00

```
Input: "padinton" && "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj"
Output: 
Return Value: "padinto"
```

P.S. I also have function that removes all duplicated chars except the first ocurrence of it from strings.
This function works after removing them

Comment: string literals are const. Allocate memory for the `char*`.

Comment: Most of this is wrong. The memory you're targeting is insufficient in size and access (it's read only). Assuming you fix that, the library routine `strcat` is for concatenating *strings*, not appending single *characters*. Ex: the first iteration of *both* loops will immediately result in a full duplication of `p1` in the target buffer because `p` (the opening character for both strings) is a match. It will just continue to compound from there.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you need to allocate memory for your return string, but also, you'll want to rethink your algorithm if you want to get the expected result. Firstly, `strcat` will add to your result string not the single character `p1[k]` but the entire rest of the string starting from character `k`. Second, if you're looping over the entirety of both strings, you'll end up adding alot more of each character than the output for each time they appear (for example, you'll be adding alot more M's since n appears twice in each string, so you'll get 4 in the result from your algorithm)

Comment: do you want to have duplicates in the result string? for example `ppadington` will give `ppadinto`

Comment: P__J__, nope my whole programm(function) should take two strings and return, without doubles, the
characters that appear in both strings, in the order they appear in the first
one. I've already finished "Duplicate removing" part. Now all I need to do is this func.

Comment: So.. you're trying to do [this](https://pastebin.com/Y17Dw2kU) ??

Comment: see my answer both versions covered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two main problems in your code are that you are not allocating space for the resulting string and you are using the `strcat` function inappropriately. Below is a brief implementation of what you are trying to achieve.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *commonString(char* p1,char* p2)
{
    const size_t lenp1 = strlen(p1);
    char *res = malloc(lenp1 + 1);
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lenp1; ++i)
        if (strchr(p2, p1[i]))
            res[j++] = p1[i];
    res[j] = 0;
    return res;
}
```

**Important Note:** The pointer returned by the `malloc` function must be checked against `NULL` before being dereferenced. It is omitted here for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues in your code.

1. Not allocating memory,
2. Modifying string literals
3. returning local variables
   etc etc.
   Your function is also inefficient. You call strlen on every iteration, call strcat (which is very expensive) just to add 1 char.

This function does what you want with or without the duplicates.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *mystrnchr(const char *str, const char ch, size_t size)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    while(size--)
    {
        if(*str == ch)
        {
            result = (char *)str;
            break;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return result;
}

char *mystrchr(const char *str, const char ch)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    while(*str)
    {
        if(*str == ch)
        {
            result = (char *)str;
            break;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return result;
}


char* commonString(char *buff, const char* p1, const char* p2, int duplicates)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    char p1c;
    while((p1c = *p1++))
    {
        if(!duplicates)
        {
            if(mystrnchr(buff, p1c, size))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(mystrchr(p2, p1c))
        {
            buff[size++] = p1c;
        }
    }
    buff[size] = 0;
    return buff;   
}


int main()
{
    char result[23];
    char *str1 = "paaaadiiiiinton";
    char *str2 = "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj";

    printf("%s\n", commonString(result, str1, str2, 0));
    printf("%s\n", commonString(result, str1, str2, 1));
}
```

You can experiment with it yourself here: https://godbolt.org/z/qMnsfa

Comment: The string API is there so use it instead of duplicating the logic. You example is somewhat far removed from the original that it's harder to follow. Better to start with a bad example and then improve it further.

Comment: @OS2 no -when someone is learning he should see and understand how it is done. 100% disagree. I understand that you try try to find a nitpick:)

Comment: @ P__J__  I believe you started the nitpicking :)
Actually a solution closer to the original problem is a better starting point. You're just assuming how you think it should be done or what the OP needs/wants. Just saying.

Comment: @ P__J__ are you serious, the original problem doesn't even run. How can it be less worse?

Comment: @ P__J__ Actually having a closer look at your example, I have to say it's just too lengthy and just as bad as anything. The OP is not that stupid that you have to spell out every operation atomically. You introduce two additional functions just to do very simple operations. The naming of your functions doesn't make it clear what the operation are.

Comment: I haven't even started with the quality of code. I believe I have made my point. 1. Reuse API. 2. Use the original problem as a viable starting point. 3. Improve and refactor as required.

Comment: @OS2 *`Use the original problem as a viable starting point. `* original code != original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution along those lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 512

void removeDup(char *result, char *string)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
  {
    char C[2] = { string[i], '\0' };

    if (strstr(result, C) == NULL)
      strcat(result, C);
  }
}

char *commonString(char *p1, char *p2)
{
  char r[MAX_LENGTH] = { };

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p1); i++)                                                                                                                                                                             
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(p2); j++)
      if (p1[i] == p2[j])
        strcat(r, &p1[i]);

  static char res[MAX_LENGTH] = { };
  removeDup(res, r);
  return res;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%s\n", commonString("padinton", "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj"));
  return 0;
}


$ cc string.c -o string && ./string
padinto
```

Comment: Beware you are making res static. A better alternative would be to define res outside the function commonString and then pass it as pointer to commonString for manipulation.

Comment: why strcat? why strlen? Why strstr ? Very inefficient and overcomplicated. This is an example of  how it should not be done.

Comment: Not necessarily, it gives the OP something to go on. using the original example. There's always ways to simplify things..

Comment: `static char res[MAX_LENGTH];` very bad idea

Comment: @ P__J__ as far as this short example is concerned it's fine. I mentioned a disclaimer at the outset.

Comment: So to find few characters you need 512 bytes of statically allocated RAM, 512 bytes on stack. RemoveDup is eve worse than the rest of the code.

Comment: here you have rewritten your functions without your unbelievable overhead (the idea of two buffers is bad but I left all of your logic). https://godbolt.org/z/x4o1xh  As you see no strcat, no strlen on every iteration etc etc.